# How to test if a PostGIS table is a raster table or vector table?

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

*Given a postgres table, is there a reliable way to test if it is a raster table?*

I am planning on importing many rasters into PostGIS and then using pgraster and geometry interoperability. As a first step, I will need to test if a table is a raster table or vector table. I think there may be ways to tell if a table is vectors, e.g. by using [Find_SRID](https://postgis.net/docs/Find_SRID.html). But I am not sure about rasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in the `public.geometry_columns`, `geography_columns` and `raster_columns` views to find a list of tables with those types of column in them.

Answer (score 1):

There are two views in the schema where Postgis instaled - `geometry_columns` for vector data and `raster_columns` fo raster data. Check you table and schema names against these views.